# The following graph makes no sense

Tags: graphing-functions

I have been asked to sketch the graph, from x = −5 to x = 5 of the odd function, $f(x)$, defined in the
interval 0 < x < 5 by the formula
$$f(x) ≡ \cos(
πx/
10)$$

The results I get are as follows :[image]

However upon inspection of the correct graph mine is wrong.
https://archive.uea.ac.uk/jtm/10/dg10p1.pdf

(Last page)

I have checked my results and can't see where it has gone wrong. any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: yours is correct  for $\cos ( \pi x / 10$ for all $x$ from $-5$ to $5.$ However, they wanted the odd extension of the part from $0$ to $5.$ This means you take the indicated part, $x > 0,$ and rotate that $180^\circ$ around the origin and draw that in.

Comment: It says "for the odd function...cosine"  But, cosine is an even function, not an odd function, so something is definitely wrong with the example.  Perhaps the author intended to use a different example and typed the wrong function.

Comment: @WillJagy : Is there a reason your answer is not an Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of English, not your mathematics. The question says:

1. $f$ is an odd function.
2. $f$ is defined to be the same as $\cos(\fracπ{10}x)$ on the interval $(0,5)$.

(1) tells you the rotational symmetry of the graph of $f$, and additionally tells you what $f(0)$ must be, which is not specified by (2). (2) tells you only what values $f$ takes on $(0,5)$, not including $0$ and $5$.

So there is a slight problem with the problem, that $f$ is not defined at $5$ and $-5$, but $f$ is indeed completely defined on the interval $(-5,5)$.

Comment: Thankyou this has certainly cleared things up :)

Comment: @FlewittConnor: You're very welcome!